# How to register formatters in Spring MVC web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications, formatter

I am facing the problem while binding nested object in Model Attribute. I have one class Book, in which I have nested class Subject as below :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

    // Other properties...
    // With all getter setter..
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="subject_id",nullable=false)
    @NotBlank(message = "Please select subject")
    private Subject subject;
    // Getter setter of subject;
}
```

Also I have implemented Formatter class for Subject as below :

```
@Component
public class SubjectFormatter implements Formatter<Subject>{

    @Autowired
    SubjectService subjectService;

    @Override
    public String print(Subject object, Locale locale) {
        return object.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public Subject parse(String id, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        return subjectService.getSubject(id);
    }
}
```

And added the formatter in spring configuration :

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.vbera.main")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.vbera.main")
public class SpringConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    //Other bean definitions...

    @Bean(name="conversionService")
    public FormattingConversionService conversionService() {
        FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean bean = new FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean();
        bean.setRegisterDefaultFormatters(false);
        bean.setFormatters(getFormatters());
        return bean.getObject();
    }

    private Set<Formatter> getFormatters() {
        Set<Formatter> converters = new HashSet<Formatter>();
        converters.add(new SubjectFormatter());
        return converters;
    }
}
```

Still I'm getting below exception on submit :

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type com.vbera.main.pojo.Subject for property subject
```

JSP view for Subject list rendering :

```
<form:label path="subject" for="subject">Subject</form:label>
<form:select path="subject" class="form-control input-md">
    <form:option value="">--- Select ---</form:option>
    <form:options items="${subjectList}" itemLabel="name"
        itemValue="id" />
</form:select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the solution from [Spring 3.1 Form and List Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471159/spring-3-1-form-and-list-binding/11472911#11472911), [Java - SpringMVC - Get parameter in the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425154/java-springmvc-get-parameter-in-the-controller/12425626#12425626) link.

In one answer, it is suggested to have below jsp select tag :

```
<form:select path="subject.id" class="form-control input-md">
<form:option value="">--- Select ---</form:option>
<form:options items="${subjectList}" itemLabel="name"
    itemValue="id" />
</form:select>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts in your `mvc.xml` file.

1. Add the bean conversion service bean:

```
<bean id="conversionService"
    class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
   <property name="formatters">
       <set>
           <ref bean="MyFormatter1" />
           <ref bean="MyFormatter2" />
       </set>
   </property>
   <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <ref bean="MyConverter1" />
            <ref bean="MyConverter2" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

2. Refer this bean in thee annotation-driven tag.

`<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />`

Using the IDs is OK most of the time. However, in forms, it would force Spring to create an empty object with the null Id instead of a null object.